# How do I insert new line in EditText field while reading the text from a file

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to create an android app in which it will take the contents of the file which is in assets, copy the contents to the file in filestorage. Then while displaying, it will read the file in filestorage and will append the lines in edittext.
The problem i am facing is empty lines are not being read.

Following is the code snippet in which i am reading the contents of asset file and copying it in file "current.txt" which will be stored in filestorage.

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new              InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("pravachan.txt")));


   ContextWrapper contextWrapper=new    ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory= contextWrapper.getDir("FileStorage",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                File myInternalFile=new File(directory,"current.txt");

                FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(myInternalFile);
                   BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(filewriter);


                String mLine = reader.readLine();

                    while (mLine != null)
                    {
                        //process line
                        if(mLine.isEmpty())
                        {
                            out.write(" ");
                            String str = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                            out.write(str);
                        }

                        else
                            out.write(mLine);


                        mLine = reader.readLine();


                    }
                    out.close();
```

Following is the code snippet in  which i am appending the edittext with contents of "current.txt" file

```
ContextWrapper contextWrapper=new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory= contextWrapper.getDir("FileStorage", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File myInternalFile=new File(directory,"current.txt");


        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(myInternalFile);

        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));


        String mLine = reader.readLine();
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        while(mLine != null)
        {
            if(mLine.isEmpty()) {
                tv.append(" ");
                String str = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                tv.append(str);

            }
            else
                tv.append(mLine);
            mLine = reader.readLine();
        }
```

I don't want empty lines to be skipped.I want the file as it is to be displayed in Edittext. Please Help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The other code snippet is in other activity. So when the user clicks that respective button the edittext field will be modified.

Comment: I can help you in debugging this. pls add a sysout statement after if(mLine.isEmpty()) { to see if program control is going in that block. I suspect its not going there. If so, we need to replace mLine.isEmpty() with some other code

Comment: Thanks Sandeep, I debugged the code . Its going in that block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer!
Instead of doing out.write(str) in which str is the line separator, I did out.newline(). It worked!